# Scala 2.8.1 => 2.9.2 RangeByOne NoSuchMethod error

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

So I'm using a graph library that has it's dependencies for Scala listed in build.sbt as 2.8.1. I tried changing it to Scala 2.9.2, and it compiled fine, but got this runtime error:

```
[error] (run-main) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.RichInt.until(I)Lscala/collection/immutable/Range$ByOne;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.RichInt.until(I)Lscala/collection/immutable/Range$ByOne;
```

It also lists the line number in the mess of errors, and I traced it to a line of code like:

```
for (i <- 0 to x)
```

I'm pretty sure Scala 2.9.2 does have the `to` method.. what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems in runtime your `x` was implicit cast to `java.runtime.RichInt`. Hence it raised error. I'm getting this issue now…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you are using some library compiled for 2.8.x with code compiled with 2.9.x. Doing that is not possible.

**Edit**

Ok, I checked out Cassovary, and I imagine you did not change the Scala version for specs. I checked what versions are available, and I suggest you change its line to this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools.testing" % "specs_2.9.1" % "1.6.9" % "test" withSources()
```

Comment: I forked the library's source code itself off GitHub and simply changed the build.sbt to indicate 2.9.2 instead of 2.8.1 - this is not done in my own project with the library's .jar file. Or can I not do that either?

Comment: @kstruct I'm not sure exactly what you did. Can you provide the sbt build file for your project? I assume the error is in your project? Or on that library?

Comment: The library. It is using Twitter's Cassovary library https://github.com/twitter/cassovary. I forked the repo, modified it's `build.sbt` to make the Scala version 2.9.2 and it gives me that above error. Specifically, if I do the `sbt test` command after I change it, it fails many of the tests, giving me the error as above.